# iOS Evaluating SSL self signed certificate by the user

Tags: ios, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm creating an iOS application which communicates with multiple hosts (servers) over SSL.

We are evaluating the peer (host) certificate trust using SecTrustEvaluate method, in case the certificate is untrusted (usually self signed), we want to show the user the certificate details, among, Issuer, DN, Issue date, Expiry date etc... in order him to decide if he wants to trust the certificate or not.

I didn't find any way to do so (extract and display all relevant certificate fields), the only attribute that I succeed to read from the DER certificate is the subject summary by using the method: SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Really nice question, I would like to know more about on this topic, I tried to search on web about this but cant find anything. :(